# How to generate dynamic labels and use the column name and value as the text

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Is there any way, if it is possible to dynamically generate the ASP.net page from code-behind.

Example:

ASP.net:

```
<div class="hidOverflow setFloatL smallPadLeft" style="width: 45%" runat="server" id="dvLeft">
</div>
<div class="hidOverflow setFloatL smallPadLeft" style="width: 45%" runat="server" id="dvRight">
</div>
```

Code-behind:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(gloString))
{
    try
    {
        strQuery = @"";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);

        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(myDataSet);

        //dynamically generate label with the SQL column name as the Text
        //dynamically generate label with the SQL column value as the text
        //<div class="hidOverflow smallPad">
            //<div class="setFloatL halfWidth vertAlignT">
                //<span class="profileLabel">{SQL COLUMN NAME}</span>
            //</div>
            //<div class="setFloatL vertAlignT">
                //<asp:Label ID="lbl1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="{SQL COLUMN VALUE}"></asp:Label>
            //</div>
        //</div>
        //.. more .. stop at the 1/2 mark of the count for the dataset and add it to the "dvLeft" div

        // STOP...

        //dynamically generate label with the SQL column name as the Text
        //dynamically generate label with the SQL column value as the text
        //<div class="hidOverflow smallPad">
            //<div class="setFloatL halfWidth vertAlignT">
                //<span class="profileLabel">{SQL COLUMN NAME}</span>
            //</div>
            //<div class="setFloatL vertAlignT">
                //<asp:Label ID="lbl1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="{SQL COLUMN VALUE}"></asp:Label>
            //</div>
        //</div>
        //.. more .. continue from the 1/2 mark of the count for the dataset and add it to the "dvRight" div
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
    }
}
```

I am looking to make it dynamic so all I have to do is change the SQL query and the labels will be generated accordingly.

I can most likely use a `asp:Repeater` control to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try binding the repeater to the Datatable ColumnCollection:

```
private DataTable _dataTable;

public void LoadRepeater()
{
    //load dataset
    _dataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
    repeater.DataSource = _dataTable.Columns;
    repeater.DataBind();
}

public string GetColumnValue(string columnName)
{
    return _dataTable.Rows[0][columnName].ToString();
}
```

Then on the repeater:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <div class="hidOverflow smallPad">
        <div class="setFloatL halfWidth vertAlignT">
            <span class="profileLabel"><%# Eval("ColumnName") %></span>
        </div>
        <div class="setFloatL vertAlignT">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text='<%# GetColumnValue(Eval("ColumnName")) %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This will only work if you have a single row on your DataTable though.

If you have more Rows, you may have to include an additional repeater for the row dimension.

### ------------------------------------------------------------------

To Split the columns, you could do something like this (untested):

```
private void LoadRepeater()
{
    //load dataset
    _dataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
    int columnCount = _dataTable.Columns.Count;
    int half = (int)columnCount/2;

    var columnCollection = _dataTable.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>();
    var firstHalfColumns = columnCollection.Take(half);
    var secondHalfColumns = columnCollection.Skip(half);

    repeater1.DataSource = firstHalfColumns;
    repeater1.DataBind();

    repeater2.DataSource = secondHalfColumns;
    repeater2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It will always be one or no rows. Ill test it out and give update. What you think of my solution?

Comment: That is awesome. Just need to split the dataset in halves by columns and use in two separate div. Thanks for leading the way :)

Comment: Can you please let me know how to split the DataTable into two separate DT by column count...

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I updated the answer with a suggestion, not sure if it's what you need.

Comment: Scheiders you saved me from writing many queries. Thank you :)